# Passing wallet argument in ethers Contract function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am trying to create an instance of a contract on ethers.

```
const example = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, contractABI, signer);
```

I am using a wallet directly instead of getting a signer through metamask ( I am aware of the risks)

Here is my "signer":

```
   const signer = new ethers.Wallet("PRIVATE_KEY");
```

When i try to execute the code I get:

```
ethers-5.5.4.esm.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value={"_isSigner":true,"address":"0x92388d12744B418eFac8370B266D31fd9C.....","provider":null}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

Do I have a syntax error? or is this not the correct way to pass a wallet as a signer

Comment: `"address":"0x92388d12744B418eFac8370B266D31fd9C....."` are you passing a valid address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might miss your provider there, you'll need to add `provider` object like this

```js
const url = "RPC Node URL"
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet("PRIVATE_KEY", provider);
```

Use the right RPC Node network to interact with the right blockchain. You can either use public or private RPC, but for production it is recommended to use private services.

Answer (score 0):

You did not connect to the signer. [From docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-connect)

```
// this creates a new contract address
new ethers.Contract( address , abi , signerOrProvider )

// Returns a new instance of the Contract, but connected to providerOrSigner.
contract.connect( providerOrSigner ) ⇒ Contractsource
```

In your code:

```
example.connect(signer)
```